# java combination of char per array

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, combinations, digits

I'm writing a program, that must find all combination:

```
String[] combination = new String[]{"123,"12","34"};
```

application must return:

```
113
114
123
124
213
214
223
224
313
314
323
324
```

There will be 81 elementnts at max in array per most of 9 character to make combination with they.
So first digit must be from `com[0]`, second from `com[1]` and so on.

Thx for help!

Comment: It's like a http://bikereviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/trek-dreadlocks-resettable-combination-cable-lock.jpg Just in some line there are 3 elements, in other 2 and so on.

Comment: If you've *always* got three input strings, this sounds like you just need loops nested 3 deep. What have you tried so far? (Note: the number of *iterations* in each loop will depend on the length of the string...)

Comment: @JonSkeet There will be 81 elements at max.

Comment: It's not clear what this sentence means, either: "There will be 81 elementnts at max in array per most of 9 character to make combination with they."

Comment: @RohitJain: Elements in what though? The input array, or the total result? What does "per most of 9 character" mean, in your view? That whole sentence is unclear IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet haha :) Yeah that is a bit confusing sentence, but one can make a wild guess what OP is talking about :)

Comment: This mean that the combination array will have from 2 to 81 elements. And each element will have from 2 to 9 chars

Comment: @user2988171: Is this what you're looking for? http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/

Comment: No, first char of new string must be from first element in array, second char from second array and so on.

Comment: @RohitJain: Nope, having read the results, I'm still none the wiser.

Comment: @user2988171: So if each element can have up to 9 characters, that suggests there can be up to 9 elements in the input array. If each of those elements has just 2 characters, that would be 512 output characters. This question is still *really* unclear.

Comment: It's 2 -81 elements in input array, each of length 2-9 @Jon Skeet

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson: Ah, I had interpreted "combination array" as the *output* (given that each element will be a combination of elements from the input). But now that I look back at the code, I see that the *input* variable is called `combination`, somewhat confusingly (and contrary to the later `com[0]` etc, too). Definitely still a poorly worded question, but I think I see what it means now. Thanks :)

Comment: Okay, now that we know what the question means - what have you (the OP) tried so far? Where are you stuck? Recursion may well help you here...

Comment: http://shrani.si/f/20/G3/1aUAH89o/fotografija0288.jpg is it clear now ? I have problem on generating all this combination

Comment: Could you design a method which takes 2 strings and returns an ArrayList<String> containing all combinations of the chars in the 2 strings? Then, can you design a method which takes an ArrayList<String> and a string and uses the first method to calclates all combinations of each string in the ArrayList<String> with the single string and adds these to a new ArrayList<String> and then returns it? If so, this should be one way (not necessarily the best way) of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's one way to do it (maybe a slightly 'ugly hack' in places)! Obviously it needs to be generalised to handle different input strings, but that should be trivial enough.

EDIT: I've made a few alterations so its closer to something dynamic, but the user input handling still remains to be done: at the moment only there's just a single 'input' array, as you can see.

```
package combinations;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Combinations {

    static String[] combination = {"123","12","34"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Combinations combinations = new Combinations();

        ArrayList<String> string = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();

        input = combinations.stringDecomposition(combination[0]);
        string = combinations.combinations(input,combination[1]);

        // next for loop starts from index i = 2 since result of combining first 2 elements
        // has just been calculated in the last line 

        for(int i = 2; i<combination.length; i++)
        {
            string = combinations.combinations(string,combination[i]);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<string.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(string.get(i));
        }

    }


        public ArrayList<String> combinations(ArrayList<String> input0, String input1){

            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

                int jlength = input1.length();

                for(int i=0; i<input0.size(); i++)
                {

                        for(int j=0; j<jlength; j++)
                        {

                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                            stringBuilder.append(input0.get(i));
                            stringBuilder.append(input1.charAt(j));
                            result.add(stringBuilder.toString());   
                        }

                }

            return result;

        }

        public ArrayList<String> stringDecomposition(String in){

            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i =0;i<in.length();i++){
                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                s.append(in.charAt(i));
                result.add(s.toString());               
            }

            return result;

        }

}
```

Comment: I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(Unknown Source)
 at Solve.combinations(Solve.java:829)
 at Solve.Resi(Solve.java:86)
 at Solve.main(Solve.java:51)

Comment: Are you still getting this error? If so, are you just running the code above, or have you added it to some of your own?

Comment: Nop, I just added 81 elements of 9 chars. So I have to save a lot of combiniation. Is there a way to print a combination in progress, not to save all of them.

Comment: I've been looking at it, but I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: I've made it. Thank you for help.

Comment: No problems. Well done. I'd be interested to see your answer: I haven't got it myself yet.